# Applying Git commits from one branch to another completely unrelated branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

So I am relatively new to Git and I am struggling with some of the concepts and which ones I should apply in order to achieve my desired target state.
I am also using Visual Studio Code for the development with the Git Source Control extension.

The source code (Marlin firmware) I am working on is available for download online but requires a number of tweaks specific to my application.
I started out by downloading their v2.1.2.1 code from Github and then created a local repo and branch in Visual Studio Code.
I decided to call my local branch 'master-2.1.2.1'.
I then created a new branch from 'master-2.1.2.1' called 'DEBUG-2.1.2.1' where I then made a number of commits specific to my needs.
Once I had a working DEBUG version, I then created a new branch from 'DEBUG-2.1.2.1' called 'V1-2.1.2.1'.
I then switched to 'V1-2.1.2.1' and made another load of commits specific to tweaks I needed to make for my needs.

I then pushed my local repo and branches to my own Github account for backup purposes.

Then Marlin v2.1.2.2 was released.
I downloaded the source code for v2.1.2.2 from Github and created a new local branch (unrelated to any of my prior branches) called 'master-2.1.2.2' and checked in all
of the new source code for v2.1.2.2 into that new branch.
I then created a new local branch from 'master-2.1.2.2' called 'WIP-2.1.2.2'
Now I am trying to work out how do I apply all my specific tweaks/commits in an intelligent way from 'v1-2.1.2.1' into 'v1-2.1.2.2' without having to try and remember all of the very specific changes I made while working on v2.1.2.1.

I cannot figure out if this is the perfect use case for Git rebase.
Remember that in my repo - branch 'V1-2.1.2.1' and 'V1-2.1.2.2' are unrelated. They are in essence two completely unrelated branches.

To help clarify things, let me try and illustrate it as follows:

BRANCH #1 FLOW ----> 'master-2.1.2.1' -> 'DEBUG-2.1.2.1' -> 'v1-2.1.2.1'
BRANCH #2 FLOW ----> 'master-2.1.2.2' -> 'v1-2.1.2.2' -> [Apply all commits from (unrelated) BRANCH #1 FLOW] -> to create my specifically tweaked 'v1-2.1.2.2'.

I hope the above makes sense.
Should I be going about this a different way?

I tried using Git cherry pick and Git rebase from within Visual Studio Code and it didn't seem to work as I intended. When I looked at a source code file from within the 'V1-2.1.2.2' source tree I expected to see my specific tweaks applied but no changes were applied so maybe I did something wrong or maybe I am not using it right or maybe I need to do it via the command line or maybe there is a bug with the Git Source Code extension available for install from the Visual Studio Code marketplace.

I am happy to do 3-way interactive merging for each commit just to make sure the latest of my specific tweaks from each of my commits is applied to the 'V1-2.1.2.2' source tree but I am struggling to see how to do that correctly. And then I got lost in a Google and YouTube rabbit hole which is why I thought it would be best to come here and ask the Stack Overflow community what I should do specific to my use case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.... to your point: the fact that the branches are not related in your repo is something that git does not care about if you will do a rebase.

So, I assume that the first commit that you did in `master-2.1.2.1` is the code *as is* from the upstream for version `2.1.2.1` and the first commit in branch `master-2.1.2.2` is the code of 2.1.2.2 from upstream.... then, the first commit in `master-2.1.2.1` will be called `X` (use the commit ID for that first commit)..... so.... you can do this:

```
git branch -f WIP-2.1.2.2 V1-2.1.2.1 # place the WIP on top of the branch that has all the stuff we want to rebase
git rebase X WIP-2.1.2.2 --onto master-2.1.2.2
```

If you feel like you *really* want to take a look at each commit, then use `-i` (interactive) when running the rebase as an *additional* option and when the commits are listed, switch `pick` for `edit` in **all** commits.... save and exit and git will stop right after applying each commit that it is rebasing.... you can do any adjustments and you will need to do `git add .; git commit --amend --no-edit` to apply those new changes you introduce *live*. When each commit is ready to move to the next you do: `git rebase --continue` and git will move to the next commit.

After rebasing is finally done (interactive or not), you will end up with `WIP-2.1.2.2` having all the tweaks you did in `V1-2.1.2.1` past the original commit `X` but applied on top of `master-2.1.2.2`.

Having solved the question in point, I wanna ask why you started a new repo from scratch. You should have cloned (even locally) the upstreasm repo and create your branches from the upstream branches or tags.

Comment: I realized this now that's what i should have done. I guess i just downloaded the official source tarballs from the Github repo for Marlin and decided well I am not planning to incorporate any of my own changes upstream so does forking or branching from their official repo really matter as it is just for my own personal use. I guess that was my rationale, no idea if I am right or wrong but that was what was going through my head at the time. Thank you for your suggestion, I can't wait to try it!